# 2 List boxes to Scale relatively

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report with has 2 rectangles side by side. I want to scale both of the same to the same size as when the number of rectangles increase.

How do I scale both of them equally as the number increases even if data in the Rectangles in not displayed(Null Values)

ScreenShot Below

[image]

Comment: What do you mean: "... has 2 rectangles.... when the number of rectangles increase..."?  Do you add rectangles or do you mean as the data fills you want to auto adjust?  I would just get rid of two seperate objects and put in a single 'list' element instead if that was the case.  Then just hover your text boxes in the proper sequence

Comment: Hello djangojazz, as the data is populated , for each group a new list is created. So I want to be able to scale both of them which are side by side equally.

Answer (score 0):

Modified the "CanGrow" and "CanShrink" properties to "false" in All the textbox in both 2 rectangles

```
CanGrow=False
CanShrink=False
```

This should work.

Comment: Hello Hiten, Thank you for the reply but I cannot make CanGrow as False , as I would need it scale.Is there a way I can make the containers(Rectangle) as CANGROW= False(I am not able to Find that Option)

Comment: You have to do that on the table as well as the tablix in both rectangle.